# How to run two form in one with one router link?

Tags: html, angularjs

I have two angular forms where one forms one consists of two fields if i click one field it should redirect to the other form which has details of the field of form 1 how to do it with one routerlink

Comment: Please Post your code to find problem in your code.

Answer (score 0):

If I am getting you correctly, on redirection you'll lose your data and your final post request is taking place at the second form.
You can try any of these:

- Before redirection, save your content in localStorage

```
localStorage.setItem('form1', {form1_data});
```

Now at the other route, you can get data from it using:

```
localStorage.getItem('form1');
```

- Similarly you can use `cookies`
- Sending the data in `params` or `query` in the route
- Making two `post` requests, i.e. one at `form1` as well. In this way you won't lose your data

Hope it helps. Cheers!